# scala: List found found : scala.collection.immutable.::[B] required: List[?U1] where type ?U1 <: U (this is a GADT skolem)

Tags: scala

I am trying to implement List(the below code) and I am getting the error mentioned in the title.

From the error I understand that :: method should take type T but actually it is given as List[T]. Or I guess it is expecting to create an apply method.

```
object List {
  def apply[T](x1: T, y1: T) = new Cons(x1, new Cons(y1, Nil))
  def apply[T]() = Nil
  def apply[T](x2: T) = new Cons(x2, Nil)
}

trait List[+T]{
    def isEmpty : Boolean
    def head : T
    def tail : List[T]
    def prepend [U >: T ] (elem : U) : List[U] = new Cons(elem, this)
    override def toString = if (this.isEmpty) "." else "{" + head + tail + "}"
    def isort [U >: T](xs: List[U]) : List[U] = xs match {
      case Nil => Nil
        case y :: ys => insert(y,isort(ys))
        }
    def :: [U >: T ] (elem: U) : List[U] = new Cons(elem, this)

    def insert[U >: T](y: T, ys: List[T]) : List[T] = ys match {
        case Nil => List(y)
        case x :: xs => if (y <= x) y :: ys else x :: insert(y , xs)
    }
}

class Cons[T](val head: T, val tail: List[T]) extends List[T]{
    def isEmpty = false
}

object Nil extends List[Nothing]{
    def isEmpty = true
    def head: Nothing = throw new Error("head.List")
    def tail: Nothing = throw new Error("tail.List")
}
```

Please suggest what parameter should the apply method have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to repair it... It's too broken. I will therefore only enumerate the main error sources:

1. **Case classes:** Neither `Nil` nor `Cons` were case classes, why do you `match` on them?
2. **Extractors:** You have neither a case-class `::`, nor any extractor called `::`, so you can't pattern match on `x :: xs`. Use your own `Cons(x, xs)` instead
3. **Ordering:** You can't call `<=` on arbitrary elements, you need an `Ordering` somewhere in scope
4. **Insert:** The signature of `insert` didn't make any sense, it takes too many arguments.

Here is a compilable (but probably still very incorrect) version:

```
object List {
  def apply[T](x1: T, y1: T) = new Cons(x1, new Cons(y1, Nil))
  def apply[T]() = Nil
  def apply[T](x2: T) = new Cons(x2, Nil)
}

import scala.math.Ordering

trait List[+T]{
    def isEmpty : Boolean
    def head : T
    def tail : List[T]
    def prepend [U >: T] (elem : U) : List[U] = new Cons(elem, this)
    override def toString = if (this.isEmpty) "." else "{" + head + tail + "}"
    def isort [U >: T](xs: List[U])(implicit ord: Ordering[U]): List[U] = xs match {
      case Nil => Nil
      case Cons(y, ys) => this.isort(ys).insert(y)
    }
    def :: [U >: T] (elem: U) : List[U] = new Cons(elem, this)

    def insert[U >: T](y: U)(implicit ord: Ordering[U]): List[U] = {
      import ord._
      this match {
        case Nil => List(y)
        case Cons(x, xs) => if (y <= x) Cons(y, xs.insert[U](x)) else Cons(x, xs.insert(y))
      }
    }
}

case class Cons[T](val head: T, val tail: List[T]) extends List[T] {
  def isEmpty = false
}

case object Nil extends List[Nothing] {
    def isEmpty = true
    def head: Nothing = throw new Error("head.List")
    def tail: Nothing = throw new Error("tail.List")
}
```

I hope it contains enough hints so you can repair the rest.